# Displaying line breaks in a comment system using Laravel

Tags: security, laravel-5.4, form-helpers

I am working on a comment system build using Laravel. Everything is working fine except that the comment line breaks are being stripped off after the comments are pulled from the database thus displaying the comment as a single string. How can I display the user content in the way it was entered without compromising my applications`s security..?

```
<div class="comments">
   <h3 class="comments-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> {{ $post->comments()->count()}} Comments</h3>
   @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
   <div class="comment-content col-md-12">
      {{ $comment->comment }}
   </div>
</div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`nl2br` - Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string.

```
{{ nl2br($comment->comment) }}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php